# Regex for 2digit number followed by hyphen

Tags: regex

I want regex to match xx-xx-xx where x can be number 0 to 9.

Comment: What did you try? add your code in the question

Comment: That's nice, and what is the question?

Comment: `[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`. Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Simplest
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}
```

if you need to be the entire line first user ^ and at the end $

```
^[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}$
```